# Set cell formula using VBA - IF & CONCATENATE

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having trouble setting a cell to a `IF` formula using VBA which will concatente if true.

```
Range("N7").Formula = "=IF(M7<0,CONCATENATE("credit",B7,M7),"")"
```

When I run this in VBA, I'm getting an end of statement error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the quotes in a string in VBA:

```
Range("N7").Formula = "=IF(M7<0,CONCATENATE(""credit"",B7,M7),"""")"
```